# Upgrading to Windows 8 - drive letters

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning

I currently have a Vista PC that I would like to upgrade to Windows 8 and I think at the same time that I will put an SSD in. So, I'm going to have 2 drives:-

1. SSD Drive (C:)
2. Old HDD (currently C:, D: and E:).

My hardware skills are a bit rusty, but what happens to drive letters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you dual boot:

- When you boot from Windows 8 you'll get C: (SSD) and D:, E:, F: (Old HDD)
- When you boot from Vista you'll get C:, D: and E: (Old HDD) and F:
  (SSD)

If you set Windows 8 to be the only boot then the first option will apply.